# How to get clang-format 14 on osx?

Tags: homebrew, llvm, clang-format

```
~/ brew upgrade clang-format
Warning: clang-format 11.0.1 already installed
```

Seems clang-format only versions upto 11 is supported on osx 10.15.7. However, we can see 14 already supported on ubuntu or debian, ref `https://apt.llvm.org/`

So how to install version 14 on osx?

Answer (score 1):

LLVM (and by extension clang-format) 14 is in a development branch and hasn't released yet. You would have to compile clang from source to actually get it. And even then it would be an incomplete possibly broken version since it's a development branch.

Comment: But why is it released on Ubuntu?

Comment: it isn't released, it's a development branch, something like a pre-alpha channel.